# Registering Listener after arriving of Message to Queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have two micro services which communicate using Rabbit MQ and deployed as separate WAR. if **service1** delivers message called **msgS1** to the queue but at that moment Service2 is down(My queue is Direct and I use routing key for message exchange), then once I boot up  my Service 2 will it be able to receive the message msg1 from queue? Currently I am receiving Null. What is correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It should, because all messages are stored in the RabbitMQ server queue. And then, your second application can get them from it. To receive messages you should properly configure your queue listener in the Spring Boot application.

It would be better, if you can provide snippets of listener that you use.

Nevertheless, you can find good examples [here](https://github.com/Dmitry-Shweikus/rabbitmq-examples).

Also, here is an example of Annotation based listener:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Component
public class RabbitMqListener {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RabbitMqListener.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
    public void processQueue1(String message) {
        logger.info("Received from queue 1: " + message);
    }
}
```